# keyboard dismiss orientation remain same

Tags: ios, uikeyboard

This is iPad application. I want to dismiss the picker-view automatic when device change orientation.Keyboard dismiss done what the orientation screen change .keyboard is dismissed and orientation was change but orientation view size move down mean it call animation function multiple time how can i solve this problem

i want to orientation screen remain 
following is my code:-

```
-(void)receivedRotate:(NSNotification *)notification{
     [self checkOrientation];       
}   
-(void)checkOrientation{
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = self.interfaceOrientation;
    @try{
        if([txtViewComponents isFirstResponder])
            [self done];

        if([txtIntervalFrequency isFirstResponder])
            [self toolbarDayBtn];

        if([textRepeated isFirstResponder])
            [self toolbarbtn];

        if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft||orientation==UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        {
             float xAxisLeftLbl=50;
             float xAxisLeftTxt=250;
             float txtWidth=230;
             float txtHeight=35;
             float lblHeight=35;
             float height=100;

             CGRect rect = CGRectMake(xAxisLeftLbl, 60, 144, lblHeight);
             lblFacility.frame = rect;
             rect = CGRectMake(xAxisLeftTxt, 60, txtWidth, txtHeight);
             txtFacility.frame = rect;

             rect = CGRectMake(xAxisLeftLbl,self.lblFacility.frame.origin.y+height , 239, lblHeight);
             lblActivityTypes.frame = rect;
             rect = CGRectMake(xAxisLeftTxt,txtFacility.frame.origin.y+height  , txtWidth, txtHeight);
             txtActivityTypes.frame = rect;

             rect = CGRectMake(xAxisLeftLbl, txtActivityTypes.frame.origin.y+height, 157, lblHeight);
             lblComponents.frame = rect;
             rect = CGRectMake(xAxisLeftTxt,txtActivityTypes .frame.origin.y+height, txtWidth, 130);
             txtViewComponents.frame = rect;

             rect = CGRectMake(xAxisLeftLbl, lblComponents.frame.origin.y+ txtViewComponents.frame.size.height+height-30, 239, lblHeight);
             lblDescription.frame = rect;
             rect = CGRectMake(xAxisLeftTxt,txtViewComponents.frame.origin.y+txtViewComponents.frame.size.height+height-30, txtWidth, 130);
             txtViewDescription.frame = rect;

             float xAxisRightLbl=500;
             float xAxisRightTxt=750;

             rect = CGRectMake(xAxisRightLbl, 60, 241, lblHeight);
             lblResponsible.frame = rect;
             rect = CGRectMake(xAxisRightTxt, 60, txtWidth, txtHeight);
             txtResponsible.frame = rect;

             rect = CGRectMake(xAxisRightLbl, txtResponsible .frame.origin.y+height,157, lblHeight);
             lblStartDate.frame = rect;
             rect = CGRectMake(xAxisRightTxt, txtResponsible .frame.origin.y+height, txtWidth, txtHeight);
             txtStartDate.frame = rect;

             rect = CGRectMake(xAxisRightLbl, txtStartDate .frame.origin.y+height, 239, lblHeight);
             lblReactivateDeactivate.frame = rect;
             rect = CGRectMake(xAxisRightTxt, txtStartDate.frame.origin.y+height, txtWidth, txtHeight);
             swicthReactivateDeactivate.frame = rect;


            rect = CGRectMake(xAxisRightLbl, lblReactivateDeactivate.frame.origin.y+height, 239, lblHeight);
             lblIntervalFrequency.frame = rect;


            rect = CGRectMake(xAxisRightTxt, swicthReactivateDeactivate.frame.origin.y+height, 55, txtHeight);
            lblevery.frame = rect;

            rect = CGRectMake(xAxisRightTxt+lblevery.frame.size.width+10, swicthReactivateDeactivate.frame.origin.y+height, 65, txtHeight);
            textRepeated.frame = rect;

            rect = CGRectMake(xAxisRightTxt+textRepeated.frame.size.width+lblevery.frame.size.width+20, swicthReactivateDeactivate.frame.origin.y+height, 94, txtHeight);
             txtIntervalFrequency.frame = rect;
             rect = CGRectMake(xAxisRightLbl,lblIntervalFrequency.frame.origin.y+height, 200, lblHeight);
             lblDeadline.frame = rect;
             rect = CGRectMake(xAxisRightTxt,txtIntervalFrequency.frame.origin.y+height, txtWidth, txtHeight);
             txtDeadline.frame = rect;

             rect = CGRectMake(0,txtDeadline.frame.origin.y+185, self.view.frame.size.width+300
                              , 60);
             bottomImage.frame = rect;

             rect = CGRectMake(420,txtDeadline.frame.origin.y+200,200,35);
             btnCreateNewActivity.frame = rect;
        }else{
              float xAxisLbl=100;
              float xAxisTxt=450;
              float txtWidth=250;
              float txtHeight=35;
              float lblHeight=35;
              float yxis=74;

              CGRect rect = CGRectMake(xAxisLbl, 40, 144, lblHeight);
              lblFacility.frame = rect;
              rect = CGRectMake(xAxisTxt, 40, txtWidth, txtHeight);
              txtFacility .frame = rect;

              rect = CGRectMake(xAxisLbl,lblFacility.frame.origin.y+yxis , 239, lblHeight);
              lblActivityTypes.frame = rect;
              rect = CGRectMake(xAxisTxt,txtFacility.frame.origin.y+yxis, txtWidth, txtHeight);
              txtActivityTypes.frame = rect;

              rect = CGRectMake(xAxisLbl, txtActivityTypes.frame.origin.y+yxis, 157, lblHeight);
              lblComponents.frame = rect;
              rect = CGRectMake(xAxisTxt,txtActivityTypes .frame.origin.y+yxis, txtWidth,130);
             txtViewComponents.frame = rect;

              rect = CGRectMake(xAxisLbl,txtViewComponents.frame.size.height+txtViewComponents.frame.origin.y+yxis-30 ,239, lblHeight);
              lblDescription.frame = rect;
              rect = CGRectMake(xAxisTxt,txtViewComponents.frame.size.height+yxis+txtViewComponents.frame.origin.y-30, txtWidth, 130);
              txtViewDescription.frame = rect;

              rect = CGRectMake(xAxisLbl, lblDescription.frame.origin.y+yxis+txtViewDescription.frame.size.height-30, 241, lblHeight);
              lblResponsible.frame = rect;
              rect = CGRectMake(xAxisTxt,txtViewDescription.frame.origin.y+yxis+txtViewDescription.frame.size.height-30, txtWidth, txtHeight);
              txtResponsible.frame = rect;

              rect = CGRectMake(xAxisLbl, txtResponsible .frame.origin.y+yxis,157, lblHeight);
              lblStartDate.frame = rect;
              rect = CGRectMake(xAxisTxt, txtResponsible .frame.origin.y+yxis, txtWidth, txtHeight);
              txtStartDate.frame = rect;

              rect = CGRectMake(xAxisLbl, txtStartDate .frame.origin.y+yxis, 239, lblHeight);
              lblReactivateDeactivate.frame = rect;
              rect = CGRectMake(xAxisTxt, txtStartDate.frame.origin.y+yxis, txtWidth, txtHeight);
              swicthReactivateDeactivate.frame = rect;

               rect = CGRectMake(xAxisLbl, lblReactivateDeactivate.frame.origin.y+yxis, 239, lblHeight);
               lblIntervalFrequency.frame = rect;

               rect = CGRectMake(xAxisTxt, swicthReactivateDeactivate.frame.origin.y+yxis, 55, txtHeight);
               lblevery.frame = rect;

               rect = CGRectMake(xAxisTxt+lblevery.frame.size.width+10, swicthReactivateDeactivate.frame.origin.y+yxis, 70, txtHeight);
               textRepeated.frame = rect;
              rect = CGRectMake(xAxisTxt+lblevery.frame.size.width+20+textRepeated.frame.size.width, swicthReactivateDeactivate.frame.origin.y+yxis, 100, txtHeight);
              txtIntervalFrequency.frame = rect;

              rect = CGRectMake(xAxisLbl, lblIntervalFrequency.frame.origin.y+yxis, txtWidth, lblHeight);

               lblDeadline.frame = rect;
              rect = CGRectMake(xAxisTxt,txtIntervalFrequency.frame.origin.y+yxis, txtWidth, txtHeight);
              txtDeadline.frame = rect;

              rect = CGRectMake(0,txtDeadline.frame.origin.y+yxis, self.view.frame.size.width+300
                                , 60);
              bottomImage.frame = rect;

              rect = CGRectMake(280,txtDeadline.frame.origin.y+yxis+10,250,35);
              btnCreateNewActivity.frame = rect;
          }
        NSLog(@"keyboardShown : %i", keyboardShown);
    }

@catch (NSException *ex) {
    [Utils LogExceptionOnServer:@"CreateActivityViewController" methodName:@"receivedRotate" exception:[ex description]];
    }

}
-(void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)aNotification {
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo]; // user info dictionary object
    // to get the keyborad size
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
     if(txtfield != nil)//textfiled set globel value  and put the value
       {
         if (txtfield.frame.origin.y>self.view.frame.size.height- kbSize.height)
           {
            raiseHeight = kbSize.height - txtfield.frame.size.height;//set the raiseaHeight vale here when its
            [self setViewMovedUp:YES];
            keyboardShown = YES;
           }

       }
    else if(txtViewActive != nil )
       {
         if(txtViewActive.frame.origin.y>self.view.frame.size.height- kbSize.height)
          {
           raiseHeight = kbSize.height - txtViewActive.frame.size.height;
           [self setViewMovedUp:YES];
           keyboardShown = YES;
           }

       }
}

-(void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification*)aNotification  {

    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];

    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    if(txtfield != nil || keyboardShown)
    {
        if (txtfield.frame.origin.y>self.view.frame.size.height- kbSize.height || keyboardShown)
        {
            [self setViewMovedUp:NO];
            keyboardShown = NO;
        }

    }
    else if(txtViewActive != nil || keyboardShown)
    {
        if(txtViewActive.frame.origin.y>self.view.frame.size.height- kbSize.height || keyboardShown)
        {
            [self setViewMovedUp:NO];
            keyboardShown = NO;
        }

    }
}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receivedRotate:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:
                                                                )
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                               object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                               object:nil];
- (IBAction)toolbarbtn{

    toolbarmonth.hidden=YES;
    toolbarDay.hidden=YES;

    [textRepeated setText:[currentArray objectAtIndex:selectedRow]];
    [textRepeated resignFirstResponder];
}
  - (IBAction)toolbarDayBtn{


    toolbarmonth.hidden=YES;
    toolbarDay.hidden=YES;
    [txtIntervalFrequency setText:[currentArray objectAtIndex:selectedRow]];
[txtIntervalFrequency resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Comment: do you want to say that keyboard is dismissed when the orientaitonchange notification received but still the orientation of the app did not change?

Comment: yes keyboard is dismissed and orientation was change but orientation view size move down mean it call animation  function multiple time how can i solve this problem